# Create Geographical regions -> countries structure and relationship with taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to replicate the geographical region-country structure of the site [United Nations](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/methods/m49/m49regin.htm).
As you can see this is the structure

1. Africa (geo_region parent):

   - Eastern Africa (geo_region child)

     - Burundi (geo_country parent)
     - Comoros (geo_country parent)
   - Middle Africa (geo_region child)

     - Angola
     - Cameroon
2. Americas (geo_region parent)

   - Latin America and the Caribbean (geo_region child)

     - Caribbean (geo_region child)

       - Anguilla (geo_country parent)
       - Bahamas (geo_country parent)

My idea is to separate regions and countries in two different taxonomies (geo_region, geo_contry) like above.

At this point everything is ok.

Now my issue is make a relationship between geo_country and geo_region.
For example I would like to create a relationship between **Bahamas** and **Caribbean** with ID.

I used [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) relationship field but the main problem is that i use the wp-json REST API and when i visit the taxonomy endpoint there is no relationship.

How i can solve this?
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advice
Alessio

Answer (score 0):

Make the *countries* a custom post type, set up taxonomies for *continents* (region parent) and the *regions*. Maybe you can even use just one taxonomy for both, but there is )was?) this weird case in WP, where it sees a difference between *just child selected* and *child and parent selected*.

That setup makes you independent from any plugin – you really, really don't want a dependency on ACF in your database, trust me. :)